# Error when trying to run jar file exported from Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

When I export my project it works, but when I open it, it says: "can't find the main-class: Game.Frame" and there is a folder called `Game` and a class in there named `Frame` and `Frame.class` is the main class.

Comment: how do you 'open' it? You mean running from a jar? See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/run.html

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like maybe your "Game" class is in a package, and you're not pointing to the package correctly.

EXAMPLE:

> http://www.jarticles.com/package/package_eng.html
>
> If you try to run this HelloWorld using java HelloWorld, you will get
>   the following error:

```
C:\world>java HelloWorld 
Exception in thread "main"
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: HelloWorld (wrong name: world/HelloWorld)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:442)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:101)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:248)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$1(URLClassLoader.java:216)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:191)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:290)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:286)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

> The reason is right now the HelloWorld class belongs to the package
>   world. If we want to run it, we have to tell JVM about its
>   fully-qualified class name (world.HelloWorld) instead of its plain
>   class name (HelloWorld).

```
C:\world>java world.HelloWorld
C:\world>Hello World
```

> Note: fully-qualified class name is the name of the java class that
>   includes its package name

Note, too, that .jar files have similar rules - if you have a package, you need to qualify the package scope.  And yes, you should *always* use "packages" (which are the moral equivalent of what .Net calls a "namespace").